# Can Google Cloud Dataflow be run without an external IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Something we noticed while working on scaling up our usage of Google Cloud Dataflow was that we would start to run up against our quota on In-use IP addresses. We are aware that requesting a quota increase is an option (and have already done so and been approved as such for CPU's) but wanted to know if it is (or is going to be) possible to run Dataflow instances without external IP addresses (both for quota reasons and because of the cost of IP addresses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently possible to run Google Cloud Dataflow instances without external IP addresses. If you need additional workers, you should request the quota increase.

Comment: This answer while correct at the time is now outdated.  Dataflow now supports workers using private IP addresses.  See Jianxin's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55386671/633150

Answer (score 10):

It's possible now. From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#public_ip_parameter):

> To turn off public IPs:
>
> Enable Private Google Access for your network or subnetwork.
>
> In the parameters of your Cloud Dataflow job, specify --usePublicIps=false and --network=[NETWORK] or --subnetwork=[SUBNETWORK].

More on the option [usePublicIps](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params)

> usePublicIps
>
> boolean
>
> Specifies whether Cloud Dataflow workers use public IP addresses. If the value is set to false, Cloud Dataflow workers use private IP addresses for all communication. In this case, if the subnetwork option is specified, the network option is ignored. Make sure that the specified network or subnetwork has Private Google Access enabled.    If not set, the default value is true and Cloud Dataflow workers use public IP addresses.

Comment: In the console UI there's an optional parameters section where you can input the text value false to turn this off too

Answer (score 6):

It's supported now...

Just add the flag

```
--disable-public-ips
```

In your gcloud command.