# Dataflow jobs fail with "Unable to bring up enough workers", quotas are OK, changing machine types and regions does not change anything

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We developed an application based on Google Cloud Platform, that uses Cloud Dataflow to write data to BigQuery. 
I am now trying to setup this application on a new GCP project on another organization.

**The problem**

I am experiencing this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776475/dataflow-job-fails-with-unable-to-bring-up-enough-workers):

> Workflow failed. Causes: Unable to bring up enough workers: minimum 1, actual 0. Please check your quota and retry later, or please try in a different zone/region.

It happens on two dataflow templates:
 1. One takes data from a Pub/Sub topic and writes to a Pub/Sub topic, 
 2. The other takes data from a Pub/Sub topic and writes to BigQuery.

Jobs are created from the Cloud Dataflow API. The templates are pretty standard, with 3 maximum workers and the `THROUGHPUT_BASED` autoscaling mode.

As suggested on similar questions, I checked the Compute engine quota, that are far from exceeded. I also changed the region, and the machine type; the problem still happens. Compute Engine and Dataflow APIs are enabled.

**The question**

As it works on projects on another organization, I believe that it comes from the GCP organization that have specific restrictions. Is it possible?
What other points should I check to make it work?

Comment: Is a billing account set on this project?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, yes a billing account is set on the project.

Comment: If you have already setup your billing and quotas correctly, this is highly unusual. I suggest contacting Google Cloud support who should be able to help you regarding this specific request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tests, we managed to make it work properly.

It was indeed not a problem with regions and machine types, though most of the related Stackoverflow threads suggest that you should start with that.

It was in fact because of a restriction on external IP addresses through a [GCP Organization policy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview). As pointed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463644/can-google-cloud-dataflow-be-run-without-an-external-ip-address), standard configuration of Dataflow requires an external IP address.